# I run this command in a unix shell console and run. But in a cleartool console I got and error

Tags: shell, unix, cleartool

```
cleartool lsact -in stream:PJ_CORE2014_pre16 | grep "deliver." | awk '{print $2}' > /system/home/archive.txt
```

I want to run this in the cleartool.exe console.

Comment: What is this command doing now? What do you want it to be doing? What is "the cleartool.exe console"? How does that differ from what you are doing now?

Comment: this command save in a file the result of listing the ativities of a determinated stream and also filter by activity name "deliver".

Comment: And is that not working? Is that not doing what you expect? What about what is currently happening **isn't** what you want?

Comment: that command is working in unix shell but not in the cleartool console. 
the grep is not recognize by cleartool... also not allow the Pipes or awk...

Comment: the cleartool console is the one located in the folder bin of the clearcase files. (cleartool.exe)

Comment: Is "the cleartool console" a unix shell? Because if it isn't then I don't know how you are going to expect this to work. Also as written that command, when run from a normal shell, will only run the `lsact` part in under `cleartool` the rest is understood by the running shell as a pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

Redirection are a feature of the shell, and a cleartool session would not allow pipe and redirection to work.

**[cleartool shell](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_shell.htm)** is a subshell is created with the same view context as the current proces

For more, see "[About cleartool and multitool interactive](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21219800)":

> ### USE OF REDIRECTION WITHIN THE INTERACTIVE SHELL
>
> **Redirection within the cleartool and multitool interactive shells is not supported**.
>
> There are a number of shell-like features that do not function within the cleartool or multitool interactive shell, and redirection is one of them.
>
> The ClearCase interactive shells are very simple shells created for ClearCase and ClearCase MultiSite operations only. These shells are not programmed to manipulate STDOUT or STDERR.
>
> The `cleartool` interactive shell doesn't support redirection (`<`, `>`, `>>`). It's also not possible to use the redirection on the command line calling `cleartool`:
>
> IE: to feed the command with argument that will not fit on the command line:

```
N:>\cleartool mkproject -nc -in projects@\PVOB < c:\file.txt
```

> The input file `c:\file.txt` will be ignored and the argument not provided.
>
> ### WORKAROUND:
>
> you can use the redirection to send the whole line into the cleartool shell.

```
N:\>cleartool < c:\file.txt
```

> You need to put the full arguments you want to pass to cleartool in the file.

Comment: @benjatosello with a cleartool shell (interactive shell), it is not supported, and is impossible indeed. With a  non-interactive cleartool command, it is supported, because executed by the native shell.